# Strange redirection to stderr with println in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, println

I do not understand if this is intentional, but if the message in `println` starts with Error, the output will be redirected to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.
Example:

```
val a = "abc"
println("NotError: $a") // to stdout
println("Error: $a") // to stderr
```

I didn't found mentions of this behaviour in Kotlin documentation, is this a bug, maybe?

Comment: I've tried in different ways and I can say that I can't replicate it. What version of kotlin are you using? Also, are there any libraries involved that might be relevant?

Comment: @Alex.T, I'm using Idea Ultimate Edition with Kotlin plugin, my JVM target version is 11 and Kotlin version is 1.4.10. I tried it again with clean project and bug still remains.
But now I'm thinking, could it be IDE related bug?

Comment: Well, I updated the plugin version and the problem was solved. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯